# Apply overflow:auto on iframe's wrapper with CSS resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, iframe-resizer

When I add `overflow: auto` on the parent element of the IFrame required by CSS `resize: both`, then *iframe-resizer* doesn't resize the IFrame but shows a scroll bar instead.

How should I solve this?

```js
iFrameResize({
  log: true,
});
```

```css
div {
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 575px;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/4.3.2/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>

<div>
<iframe src="http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve]

Comment: I added example code.

Answer (score 0):

Add height to iframe:

```
iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That was not the issue... But seem the utility class of bootstrap use !important so by using normal CSS it's works fine.


My code was:

```
<div class="overflow-auto">
  <iframe src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

By adding style overflow: auto without !important it's work fine.

Height: 100% or not it works.

Answer (score 0):

Seem the issue was caused by utility class of bootstrap which use !important so by using normal CSS it works fine.

My code was:

```
<div class="overflow-auto">
  <iframe src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

By adding style overflow: auto without !important it work fine.

Height 100% or not it works.